# I want to call a function with logfile name as argument using thread in python

Tags: python, logging

```
import threading
import logging, logging.handlers


class FuncThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, target, *args):
        self._target = target
        self._args = args
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        self._target(*self._args)

def someOtherFunc(data, key, testlogfile):
    #initialize logging system
    testlogger = logging.getLogger("testlogger")
    testlogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    file = open(testlogfile,'w')
    file.close()
    # This handler writes everything to a file.
    h1 = logging.FileHandler(testlogfile)
    f = logging.Formatter("%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(funcName)s %(lineno)d %(message)s")
    h1.setFormatter(f)
    h1.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    testlogger.addHandler(h1)
    testlogger = logging.getLogger("testlogger")
    testlogger.debug("someOtherFunc was called : data=%s; key=%s" % (str(data), str(key)))

t1 = FuncThread(someOtherFunc, [1,2], 4, "output1.log")
t1.start()
t1.join()

t2 = FuncThread(someOtherFunc, [2,4], 8, "output2.log")
t2.start()
t2.join()

t3 = FuncThread(someOtherFunc, [3,6], 9, "output3.log")
t3.start()
t3.join()
```

---

The problem above is output1.log is having 3 log messages logged for all t1,t2 and t3 threads.I want output1.log to have only t1 thread logs and respectively

Comment: What is off-topic about this question?

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
testlogger = logging.getLogger("testlogger")
```

Each thread is getting the same logger. Try changing it to this:

```
testlogger = logging.getLogger(testlogfile)
```

Comment: I tried changing it,but it didn't help.This time there is no log captured.Just empty log files are created.

Comment: Figured it out..I need to remove the handler at the end like this
testlogger.removeHandler(h1)